# Placeholder attribute not working in Concrete5 site

Tags: php, placeholder, concrete5

I am working on one concrete5 site and need to add text using placeholder in concrete5's default search block.
Edited the code like this:

```
<input name="query" type="text" value="<?php echo htmlentities($query, ENT_COMPAT, APP_CHARSET)?>" class="ccm-search-block-text" placeholder="Search"/>
```

file path is : siteroot\concrete\blocks\search\view.php.
When I use the same stuff in local Apache server, its working. But not working with other server.

Any ideas or suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Are you testing with the same browser ? What's the generated code ?

Comment: It is not working with any of the browsers, tested with all. Whereas in apache the same is working with all browsers.
Generated code is: <input type="text" class="ccm-search-block-text" value="" name="query"> 
Placeholder attribute is not present at frontend..!

Comment: Are you sure you have the right PHP file on the not working server ? If so, you might have a cache problem.

Comment: Yes file is correct because it is working with apache. And yes, cleaned cache from browser and from site backend as well.Still the same :/. Now I have no clue what is the issue.

Comment: looks like you are not using the correct php `placeholder="Search"` part should have been generated code. are you using any caching at server?

Comment: No. I am not using any caching.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you either changed code in the wrong part of the template (which is easy to do because the markup for the built-in blocks is *extremely* messy and not well-thought-out), or you have another file that is overriding the base view.

First of all, you should not edit the built-in view.php file -- instead you should override it by copying the file to `SITEROOT/blocks/search/view.php`. Now in that new copy of the file, make the changes you want to.

Next, try making some other changes and see if those come through -- for example, try just adding some random text to the file and see if that gets displayed. The search block combines a lot of different functionality into one place, so it's possible you're changing the file in one spot but that spot is never actually rendered (for example, the search block outputs both the search form *and* the search results when the form is submitted).

Also you should disable the Overrides Cache in the dashboard -- this causes a lot of problems of this nature during development.

There isn't anything in the search block itself that would change your markup, so it's probably due to caching or not having your code in the place that you think it's in.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea..  Rather than trying to add to the php outside of Concrete, why not try this?  I have used it a number of times with our sites that I have put together..

https://www.concrete5.org/marketplace/addons/simple-php-block/

HTH,

Kent